# Pass 'typed text' from bash interactive shell to a command

Tags: bash, line-editor

I would like to pass whatever the user has typed in a bash shell to a command, when the user presses a keyboard binding|shortcut

For example : Lets say Ctrl+b is our binding

```
bind '"\C-b": "myCommand.sh"'
```

User types `tar czv` then presses the shortcut—which passes the string 'tar czv' to mycommand.sh

Is this possible at all ? The only way I can think of is to pass it after echoing it.

```
bind '"\C-b": " \e[1~ echo '\''\e[4~'\''| mycommand.sh\n"'
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Bash and zsh are completely different here, that should be two separate questions. I've removed the mention of zsh from your question since you have a bash answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I exactly understand, but this seems to do what you want (?).

```
bind '"\C-b": "\C-a\C-kecho \'\'\\C-y\'\\' | myCommand.sh\n"'
```

The quoting gets tricky. Easier in ~/.inputrc:

```
"\C-b": "\C-a\C-kecho \'\C-y\' | myCommand.sh\n"
```

Instead of echoing, what about having the script take a command line argument instead? Again, in ~/.inputrc:

```
"\C-b": "\'\C-amyCommand.sh \'\n"
```